# How to create a table in Excel that reads values from other tables and displays all the unique entries for each header?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel workbook that a bunch of worksheets. Each worksheet has a table (with headers).

A lot of these tables have the same headers (e.g. the header `"Cars"` might be present in the table on worksheets 1, 4, 5, 6).

Also, under each header a lot of these tables have the same values (e.g. the values `"Mustang"`, `"Camaro"`, and `"Corvette"` might be present under the `"Cars"` header in worksheets 1, 5, and 6).

I would like to create a new worksheet that contains a table that pulls all the headers from each table in each worksheet and then lists all the **unique** values for that header.

How can I do this? I'm absolutely clueless about Excel, but I know how to code so I should be able to figure this out if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: It's tedious job and I do  believe that VBA macro is best suitable to achieve the goal,, if macro suits you then please [Edit] your post and include some sample data also,, add TAG `VBA` to the post.

Comment: Yes, there is no such build-in feature to do this, you may follow @Rajesh S's suggestion to post a new thread on how to solve the problem using VBA for help.